# custom aggregation of one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

with a table `table1` like below

```
+------+-----+------+----------+-----------+
| city | day | hour | car_name | car_count |
+------+-----+------+----------+-----------+
|    1 |  12 |   00 | corolla  |         8 |
|    1 |  12 |   00 | city     |         9 |
|    1 |  13 |   00 | corolla  |        17 |
|    1 |  13 |   00 | city     |         2 |
|    1 |  14 |   00 | corolla  |         3 |
+------+-----+------+----------+-----------+
```

for each `city, day , hour` need to find out the difference `count_diff` in the `car_count` for `car_name`s corolla and city excluding those when both or either of them is not present. `count_diff` is essentially `[ (count of corollas) - (count of city) ]`

**expected output**

```
+------+-----+------+-----------+
| city | day | hour | count_diff|
+------+-----+------+-----------+
|    1 |  12 |   00 | -1        | 
|    1 |  13 |   00 | 15        | 
+------+-----+------+-----------+
```

Comment: assuming there cant be several corollas for sam ehour?..

Comment: yeah, there can't be more than one record per `city, day, hour, car_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data as 
(select city, day, hour , 
    sum(case when  car_name = 'corolla' then car_count else 0 end) corolla_count, 
    sum(case when  car_name = 'city' then car_count else 0 end) as city_count
 group by city, day, hour
) 
select city, day, hour, corolla_count - city_count from data 
where corrolla_count > 0 and city_count > 0
```

You could try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
t=# with a as (
  select
  *
  , count(1) over a
  , car_count - lead(car_count) over a count_diff
  from table1
  window a as (partition by city,day,hour)
)
select city,day,hour,count_diff
from a
where count >1 and count_diff is not null;
 city | day |  hour  | count_diff
------+-----+--------+------------
    1 |  12 |    00  |         -1
    1 |  13 |    00  |         15
(2 rows)

Time: 0.411 ms
```